# Center vertically 2 items inside another centered div

Tags: html, css

Here's what i want:

[image: imgs centered]

And here's what i've done so far:

[image: done]

What i don't know how to do in a better way is how to center the divs inside the panel, heres the html:

```
<section id="purchases-dashboard" class="container">

    <div class="dashboard-options row panel">

        <div class="col-md-4 text-center dashboard-option">

            <img src="http://www.nucanorthtexas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/supplier-icon.png" alt="Proveedores">

            <p>Proveedores</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center dashboard-option">

            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty_office_3/256/inventory-maintenance.png"
                 alt="Supplier">

            <p>Productos</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center dashboard-option">

            <img src="http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/SUPERVISTA/accounting/jpg/256/inventory_icon.jpg" alt="Supplier">

            <p>Inventario</p>

        </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

And the css:

```
.dashboard-options {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}

.dashboard-option > img {

    width: 170px;
    height: 140px;

}
```

What i need is to know how to center vertically the `.dashboard-option` class divs... notice that i've centered the `.dashboard-options` div.

Comment: In addition to your vertical problem you may want to check out flexbox, which can distribute your items horizontally extremely easy and flexible with no needs for fixed container dimensions.

Comment: I'm trying to use flex but if i do `display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between;` the items doesn't get centered vertically @Marian

Comment: You wouldn't use flex-direction `column` for a horizontal layout. [Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Deridjian/ae5gyk58/). If it doesn't work in your browser add the required prefix. I didn't bother to prefix at all. [This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a pretty good explanation of flexbox.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks, but now i've got another problem would you please join @Marian at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95100/css-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add `padding-top: 75px;` to `.dashboard-options`

Comment: Take note that this requires you to always recalculate and rewrite code if you change dimensions or concepts. There's other approaches that provide way more flexible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply center an element *vertically* using the `translate` property; you won't have to mess with `margin` or `padding` and it's quite easy.

```
.class {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/987h1357/), with the above code in use to *vertically* and *horizontally* center and element, inside of another that is positioned `absolute`. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/987h1357/1/) of *multiple* elements *vertically* centered.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.dashboard-options {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.dashboard-option {
    background: blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-options">
    <div class="dashboard-option"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I usually use this approach in these days with transform prefixed well for older browsers. Works always, horizontally and vertically and no need to use margins, paddings, floats, absolute positioning, flexbox or similar much more complicated ways.

Comment: @Marian and it's so easy to implement; completely agree w/you!

Answer (score 0):

Just make `height: auto` and do a `padding: 20px 0` for `.dashboard-options`
and also remove

```
bottom: 0; 
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

because you have `width`, and a `margin`

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zpgazxLp/)

UPD:

[fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pc2ywq57/)

Comment: Mmmm, actually without the `bottom: 0; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` it's not vertically centered anymore

Answer (score 0):

This class will vertically center anything:

```
.vert {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```